# change event handler in angular not reading options value from select

Tags: angular, typescript, event-handling

I am trying to get the onPageSizeUpdate function to read the value of option when selected but does not seem to be able to read the value as shown by the logs. Any help?

### html

````
    <div class="col-md-3 mt-2" style="text-align: right;">
                      <span class="mr-2">Page Size</span>
                      <select (change)="onPageSizeUpdate($any($event.target).value)">
                        <option value="" selected="true">5</option>
                        <option value="">10</option>
                        <option value="">20</option>
                        <option value="">50</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
    ```
    ## typescript ##
    onPageSizeUpdate(pageSize) {
        console.log(pageSize);
        console.log("working");
      }
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
onPageSizeUpdate($any($event.target).value)
```

1. Just do

   onPageSizeUpdate($event)

and the method:

```
onPageSizeUpdate(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value)
}
```

2. Or:

   onPageSizeUpdate($event.target.value)

and the method:

```
onPageSizeUpdate(event) {
    console.log(event)
}
```

EDIT: Well, we all missed the obvious: your options have an empty value -_-

```
<option value="">50</option>
```

So just add a value: `<option value="50">50</option>`

Comment: Thanks. Tried all before none worked. I added the $any because without it, the 'value' in event.target was showing error.

Comment: Edited my answer. Only now noticed the problem with your options xD

Comment: Yeah. That was the problem. Thanks very much for the assistance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NgModelChange` instead , but you need to add `ngModel`

so your code will be something like

```
    <div class="col-md-3 mt-2" style="text-align: right;">
                      <span class="mr-2">Page Size</span>
                      <select [(ngModel)]="myVar" (ngModelChange)="onPageSizeUpdate()">
                        <option value="" selected="true">5</option>
                        <option value="">10</option>
                        <option value="">20</option>
                        <option value="">50</option>
                      </select>
                    </div>
```

and TS

```
myVar ; 
onPageSizeUpdate() {
    console.log(this.myVar)
}
```

this will give you more control if you want to change `myVar` value from the TS file

Comment: Tried this. Still wasn't getting the value. I don't know why, but everything I try seems not to get the value of the options.